# Troubleshooting to implement SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have this table called `InspectionsReview`:

```
CREATE TABLE InspectionsReview
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    InspectionItemId  int, 
    SiteId  int,
    ObjectId int,
    DateReview  DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Here how the table looks:

```
+----+------------------+--------+-----------+--------------+
| ID | InspectionItemId | SiteId | ObjectId  | DateReview   |
+----+------------------+--------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 3                |  3     | 3045      |  20-05-2016  |
|  2 | 5                |  45    | 3025      |  01-03-2016  |
|  3 | 4                |  63    | 3098      |  05-05-2016  |
|  4 | 5                |  5     | 3041      |  03-04-2016  |
|  5 | 3                |  97    | 3092      |  22-02-2016  |
|  6 | 1                |  22    | 3086      |  24-11-2016  |
|  7 | 9                |  24    | 3085      |  15-12-2016  |
+----+------------------+--------+-----------+--------------+
```

I need to write trigger that checks before the new row is inserted to the table if the table already has row with columns values 'ObjectId' and 'DateReview' that equal to the columns values of the row that have to be inserted, if it's equal I need to get the ID of the exited row and to put to trigger variable called `duplicate` .

For example, if new row that has to be inserted is:

```
INSERT INTO InspectionsReview (InspectionItemId, SiteId, ObjectId, DateReview)]  
VALUES (4, 63, 3098, '05-05-2016');
```

The duplicate variable in SQL Server trigger must be equal to 3.

Because the row in `InspectionsReview` table were ID = 3 has `ObjectId` and `DateReview` values the same as in new row that have to be inserted. How can I implement this?

Comment: what is the datatype of id column ?is it identity ?

Comment: this part is also not clear.."I want to get the ID of the row and to put it to trigger varialble called duplicate"  can you please show sample expected output

Comment: For this part "I need to write trigger that checks before new row inserted to the Inspections Review" and this " if it is, I want to get the ID of the row and to put it to trigger varialble called duplicate". If you do the check **before** inserting, then how can you get the ID to insert to another table?

Comment: @DVT I updated my question, hope it more 
clearer.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I updated question please see it

Comment: @Michael My bad. I thought the ID was auto_generated.

Comment: @Michael:So when new insert happens with existing values like this.."VALUES ( 4, 63, 3098, '05-05-2016' )" you want that new row id value to be 3?

Comment: @Michael You keep mentioning the duplicate variable? Is it a column in the logging table where you log the duplicate?

Comment: SQL Server **doesn't have** an `AUTO_INCREMENT` option in the table stucture - either you're using something else other than SQL Server, or this is *not* the SQL Server table create script ...

Answer (score 0):

With the extra assumption that you want to log all the duplicate to a different table, then my solution would be to create an AFTER trigger that would check for the duplicate and insert it into your logging table.
Of course, whether this is the solution depends on whether my extra assumption is valid.

Here is my logging table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.InspectionsReviewLog (
    ID int
    , ObjectID int
    , DateReview DATETIME
    , duplicate int
);
```

Here is the trigger (pretty straightforward with the extra assumption)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_InspectionsReview
ON dbo.InspectionsReview
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tableVar TABLE(
        ID  int
        , ObjectID int
        , DateReview DATETIME
    );

    INSERT INTO @tableVar (ID, ObjectID, DateReview)
    SELECT DISTINCT inserted.ID, inserted.ObjectID, inserted.DateReview
    FROM inserted
        JOIN dbo.InspectionsReview ir ON inserted.ObjectID=ir.ObjectID AND inserted.DateReview=ir.DateReview AND inserted.ID <> ir.ID;

    INSERT INTO dbo.InspectionsReviewLog (ID, ObjectID, DateReview, duplicate)
    SELECT ID, ObjectID, DateReview, 3
    FROM
        @tableVar;


END;
```